# how to make my question and answer bot more detailed or accurate

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface, nlp-question-answering

I am using hugging face to make a question and answer bot there are a few questions I've entered and it gave a few word answers but I am unable to get the link or the full context to show, I was wondering if there is a way to make the bot more accurate, below is my code

```
import streamlit as st
import transformers
from transformers import pipeline

def create_qa_bot():
    # Load the question-answering pipeline
    qa_pipeline = pipeline("question-answering")

    return qa_pipeline

def ask_question(context, question, qa_pipeline):
    # Use the pipeline to answer the question based on the context
    result = qa_pipeline(context=context, question=question)

    return result['answer']

def main():
    # Create the question-answering bot
    qa_bot = create_qa_bot()

    # Example context and questions
    context = "To reset your password, go to the forget password link and a code will be sent to your email, then go to this link: www.google.com."

    st.title("Question Answering App")
    input_text = st.text_area("Question", value="Enter question here")
    
    # Ask questions and print answers
    if input_text == "Enter question here":
        st.markdown("A:")
    else:
        answer = ask_question(context, input_text, qa_bot)
        st.markdown(f"A: {answer}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Example input and output:
Input: How do I reset my password
Output: Go to the forget password link

Input: Can I get the link to reset my password
Output: Go to the forget password link

Input: What should I do after getting a code to my email
Output: go to the forget password link

Input: What is the Eiffel tower
Output: forget password link